# Android App integration with Firestore: Could not reach firestore backend

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble fetching data from firestore on android app.

Just for testing, I was trying to get data as follows:-

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        this.collectionReference = db.collection("userData/tracking/users/someuser/books");
        db.document("userData/tracking").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentPath.isEmpty())
                {
                    //some code....
                }
            }
        });

Note: userData/tracking/**users/someuser/books** part in bold doesn't exists. 
userData/tracking document exists.

But running the android app on debug mode, I get the following errors on console:-
W/common.FileUtils: Failed to set dir world executable: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/files/gmscore_global_dirs.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
W/common.FileUtils: Failed to set dir world executable: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/files/gmscore_global_dirs.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
W/common.FileUtils: Failed to set dir world executable: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/files/gmscore_global_dirs.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
W/common.FileUtils: Failed to set dir world executable: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/files/gmscore_global_dirs.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
W/linker: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_extracted_libs/x86/libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0x91
V/NativeCrypto: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 279 native methods...
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20733(1775KB) AllocSpace objects, 34(680KB) LOS objects, 6% free, 34MB/37MB, paused 12.506ms total 132.706ms
I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Firestore backend.
```

Pardon me for any silly mistakes as I am using `Firestore` for the first time. Surely, I am missing something trivial. Any help or suggestions will be great!

Comment: Are you sure you have a connection to the server?

Comment: Yes, in fact I had sent this question to the firestore support team. They replied back saying this is a known issue and working on the fix.

Comment: I will post my answer as soon as I get updates from Firestore Support team.

Comment: That's good. Please aslo leave a comment when you do.

Comment: This issue is resolved by Google support. No longer a problem.

Comment: What was the response from Google support?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the rules properly. If you are developing an app you mostly don't require authentication right now. So try this in `Rules` Tab:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashish, I have done this as well. I had sent this question to the firestore support team. They replied back saying this is a known issue and working on the fix. Thank you again!

Comment: Ohh great then. Happy developing!!